# C# Multiple Tasks and report progress

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, xamarin, task

I need some help with **multiples tasks** and **reporting** progress in C#. I'm trying to use in `Xamarin`, but just to simplify, the following code snippets was made using `WindowsForm` (WinForms).

I need to run a Loading Form which executes a task. This task should report its progress to the loading form, changing a property which controls the label of a status message.

Everything I tried so far is not working. The Loading Form doesn't update its status message while the Task is running. So, where should I declare the `Progress` variable and how am I supposed to pass it to the task? How this communication should work?

**This is my main form:**

```
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            frmLoading loading = new frmLoading();

            // THIS BLOCK SHOUD BE HERE?
                Progress<string> progress = new Progress<string>(updateValue =>
                {
                    loading.ChangeMessage(updateValue);
                });
            //END


            loading.Start(() => Count(loading.progress)); //PROGRESS from LOADING or from this class?

            loading.ShowDialog();
        }


        private async Task<int> Count(IProgress<string> progress)
        {

            int returnValue = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {

                Thread.Sleep(100);

                if (progress != null)
                {

                    if (i <= 20)
                    {
                        progress.Report("Keep waiting...");
                    }
                    else if (i > 20 && i <= 40)
                    {
                        progress.Report("Hold on...");
                    }
                    else if (i > 40 && i <= 80)
                    {
                        progress.Report("So close!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        progress.Report("All right!");
                    }

                }

                returnValue = i;
            }

            await Task.Run(() => { MessageBox.Show("Completed!"); });

            return returnValue;

        }

    }
```

**And this is my loading form:**

```
        public partial class frmLoading : Form, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private Func<Task<int>> taskParam;

        public Progress<string> progress;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public string currentMessage { get; set; }

        public frmLoading()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            progress = new Progress<string>(updateMessage => {
                currentMessage = updateMessage;
            });

        }

        public async Task<int> StartTask()
        {

            return await taskParam();

        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await StartTask();
        }

        public void Start(Func<Task<int>> taskParam)
        {
            this.taskParam = taskParam;
        }

        public void ChangeMessage(string newMessage)
        {
            currentMessage = newMessage;
        }


        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {

            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

            if (propertyName.Equals(nameof(currentMessage)))
                lblProgress.Text = currentMessage;

        }

    }
```

Comment: You're using `Thread.Sleep()` to represent work, but that just blocks the thread. It doesn't give the thread any way to respond to window messages, which would be needed to update the window. Use `Task.Delay()` instead, per duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

> Everything I tried so far is not working.

That's because `Count` is almost entirely synchronous. If you got rid of the `await Task.Run`, then the compiler would warn you that it will run synchronously.

If you have asynchronous work to do, then replace `Thread.Sleep` with `await Task.Delay`. If you have synchronous work to do, then do that work within a `Task.Run`, as such:

```
loading.Start(() => Task.Run(() => Count(loading.progress)));
```